# Why are my class functions executed when importing the class?

Tags: python-3.x

it's probably a very basic question but I was unable to find an answer that I could thoroughly understand.

In my main program **main_program.py**, I'm importing a class that itself imports another class:

**in main_program.py**:

```
from createTest import *
```

**in createTest.py:**

```
print("TEST")
from recordRecallQused import *
print("TEST")
```

**now in recordRecallQused:**

```
class recordRecallQused:

    def __init__(self, path):

        self.path = path

        try:
            with open(self.path, 'r',newline = '') as question_used:
                question_used.closed
        except IOError:
            #if file doesnt exist
            print("the file doesn't exist")
            with open(self.path, 'w',newline = '') as question_used:
                question_used.closed


    def recallQused(self):
        list_Qused = []
        print("I'm being executed")
        with open(self.path, 'r',newline = '') as question_used:
            questionused = csv.reader(question_used)
            for item in questionused:
                if len(item)>0:
                    list_Qused.append(item[0])       
            question_used.closed

        return list_Qused
```

What I obtain in the kernel:

```
>TEST
>I'm being executed
>TEST
```

so functions inside the class are executed even though they are not called, but I have read that it's "normal", "def" are no statements but "live" things.

Still, I have tried something much more simple:

**in main_program_TEST.py**

```
from class1 import *

a = class1()
```

**in class1.py:**

```
print("t")
from class2 import *
print("t")
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def message(self):
        print("prout")
```

**in class2.py:**

```
class class2:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def message(self):
        print("prout2")
```

When executing **main_program_TEST.py** the kernel displays

```
>t
>t
```

so this time the functions in class2.py have not been executed, otherwise the kernel would show instead:

```
>t
>prout2
>t
```

I really wonder why.

Comment: Some code you have not shown here is calling `recallQused`.

Comment: I guess you have a name collision with another module named `recordRecallQused`.  Try renaming the file.

Comment: Why do you keep doing `question_used.closed`? What do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Rauch you are right, part of my code in **recordRecallQused.py** was calling the function.

```
"""#load all list
print("loading questions info")
# questions info: answers, category
list_AllQ = []
with open('questionsInfoTo130.csv', newline = '') as csvfile:
    questionsInfo = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # loop over the questions information rows
    for (i,row) in enumerate(questionsInfo):
        if(i!=0):
           list_AllQ.append(row)
    csvfile.close()


path = 'question_used.csv'"""

list_AllQ = [[0,1,2,1,"que"],[0,1,2,2,"que"],[0,1,2,3,"que"],[0,1,2,4,"que"],[0,1,2,55,"que"],[0,1,2,6,"que"],[0,1,2,7,"que"],[0,1,2,8,"que"],[0,1,2,9,"que"]]

a = recordRecallQused('question_used.csv')
list_Qused = a.recallQused()
list_avQ = a.createListavQ(list_Qused, list_AllQ)
list_Qtest = a.createListQtest(list_avQ)
a.recordQused(list_Qtest)
```